# Editing .play code sections inside Golang present presentation

Tags: go

I'm working on introductory Golang course, and wanted to insert something like https://play.golang.org/ embeddings into my slides. I found out about golang.org/x/tools/present package, and decided to use it for my slides. I insert examples into my in `.slide` file using:

```
.play hello.go
```

which works almost as expected. I'm just not able to edit example from browser.

In `GOPATH/src/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/present/templates/action.tmpl` I see following code:

```
{{define "code"}}
  <div class="code{{if playable .}} playground{{end}}" {{if .Edit}}contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false"{{end}}>{{.Text}}</div>
{{end}}
```

Which suggests that it is possibly editable. But how to enable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual, RTFM, in [present documentation](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/present):

> The .code function may take one or more flags immediately preceding
>   the filename. This command shows test.go in an editable text area:
>
> .code -edit test.go

Same works for the `.play` command, because as documentation tells us "The function "play" is the same as "code"":

```
.play -edit hello.go
```